# How to toggle two images onClick

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, treeview

I'm making a collapsible treeView.
I made it all, I just need my `+` and `-` icons to toggle whenever they are clicked.

I did the part when I change an icon from `+` to `-`, on click, with jQuery with the following code:

```
$(this).attr('src','../images/expand.gif');
```

Problem is, I don't know how to make it go other way around, when i click on the node again :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery toggle to change image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062731/jquery-toggle-to-change-image)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
<style>
.expand{
    content:url("http://site.com/expand.gif");
}
.collapse{
    content:url("http://site.com/collapse.gif");
}
</style>

<img class="expand">
<script>
//onclick code
$('img.expand').toggleClass('collapse');
</script>
```

Comment: Can you lpease tell me how to do this part, when i want to do it locally ( so no URL in css)

Comment: Try using content:url('./images/expand.gif');

Answer (score 3):

Look for jquery function toggleClass :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Ceptu/

Html:

```
<div id="box">

    Hello :D

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#box").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

Css:

```
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.red {
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

Remember that !important is realy important!!!

Lots of ways to do this :D

Comment: Happy i can help, best way with images bigger than 25x25 is loading the image before you call him to show, show but him offscreen: Meaning using postion and left:-1000px;

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do this without making classes. Inside your click event function, you could do something like this:

```
if($(this).attr('src') == '../images/collapse.gif')
   $(this).attr('src', '../images/expand.gif');
else
   $(this).attr('src', '../images/collapse.gif');
```

Answer (score 0):

add plus as a default img src then define a minus-class to change the image source to minus image

```
$("selector_for_your_link").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("minus-class");
    });
```