# Get Specific Div Content Based On Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get specific div content based on id. As an example, I've the following contents one by one in the front-end using div:

```
Question 1
```

User clicks next, then the second question within the div and so on will come up. When there will be no questions left and user clicks next again, it'll show the question numbers as follows: Say for three questions at the end, a similar list will appear in the front-end

```
Question 1 Question 2 Question 3
```

When user will click in any of the question, it should take the user to that specific question. Notice that, this isn't an anchor and it has to be done using the div section. Here's a fiddle that I was trying to work with - [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0ecf61u/5/)

In the code, I've a div area that remains hidden initially, specifically the question numbers that'll appear at the end. So it reaches the last question, it enables that div area and shows the question number. Here is the code snippet:

```
$(".getVal").click(function () {
    var $container = $('.divs').children().eq();

    var id = $(".h2Val").text().trim();
    var id2 = $(this).attr("data-id"); //Assigned data-id to match the question id
    
    if (id.match(id2)) { //When match found, trying to enable the div with question
         $(".hideSection1").show();
         $(".hideSection2").hide();
    }
});
```

Now the problem I face, is it actually possible to get that specific div with question as this isn't an anchor or href or any better way to overcome this issue? In my case, it shows the question but the last one but required to obtain corresponding questions clicking on question numerbers.

**Code Snippet**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hideSection2").hide();

  divs = $(".divs").children();
  divs.each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  var index = 0,
    divs = $(".divs").children();

  //declare
  var indexes = 0;
  $(".button").click(function() {
    //get div length
    var lengths = divs.length;
    //checking if btn clicked is next
    if ($(this).is('#next')) {
      //checking if value if less then length
      if ((indexes < (lengths - 1))) {
        //increment
        //remove 
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        console.log("in  - " + indexes)
        //show div
        index = (index + 1) % divs.length;
        divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
        //to show result
        show_data1(indexes);
        indexes++;
      } else {
        $(".hideSection2").show();
        $(".hideSection1").hide();
        console.log("i am in last question reached")
        $(this).prop('disabled', true); //disable
        $(this).css("background-color", "#00FFFF"); //chnagecolor

        $("#prev").css("background-color", "blue");

      }
    } else if ($(this).is('#prev')) {
      //chcking id value is not 0
      if (indexes != 0) {
        //remove 
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        indexes--;
        //show
        index = (index - 1) % divs.length;
        divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
        console.log("back  - " + indexes)
        show_data1(indexes); //show result
      } else {
        console.log("no back question")
        //disabled
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        //add color chnage
        $(this).css("background-color", "#00FFFF");
        $("#next").css("background-color", "blue");

      }
    }
  });

  function show_data1(indexes1) {
    //pass indexes value to get required div
    var $container = $('.divs').children().eq(indexes1);

    var id = $container.find(".h2Val").text().trim();
    var $checked = $container.find('.cbCheck:checked');
    var values = $checked.map(function() {
      return this.value
    }).get();
    //console.clear()
    console.log('ID: ' + id + ' has ' + $checked.length + ' checked');
    console.log('Values: ', values.join())

  }

  $(".getVal").click(function() {
    var $container = $('.divs').children().eq();

    var id = $(".h2Val").text().trim();
    var id2 = $(this).attr("data-id");
    //alert($(this).attr("data-id"));

    if (id.match(id2)) {
      //alert(id + $(this).attr("data-id"));
      $(".hideSection1").show();
      $(".hideSection2").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideSection1">
  <div class="divs">
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="h2Val">1</div>
      <div>What's the capital of England?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val1" class="cbCheck" name="val1" value="London" />London</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val2" class="cbCheck" name="val2" value="New York" />New York</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="heading">
      <div class="h2Val">2</div>
      <div>Who invented computer?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val3" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val4" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val5" class="cbCheck" name="val5" value="Sir Isaac Newton" />Sir Isaac Newton</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="h2Val">3</div>
      <div>Who invented computehttr?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="button" id="prev">Previous</a>
  <a class="button" id="next">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="hideSection2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="divs2">
        <a class="getVal" data-id="1">1</a>
        <a class="getVal" data-id="2">2</a>
        <a class="getVal" data-id="3">3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking us to help you with...

Comment: Still seems like a lot of irrelevant code here in order for us to understand what your specific issue is.

Comment: I apology for the snippet but without those, it would be hard to understand the scenario. But the **.getVal** section is the main part where I am stuck. I would request to run the code snippet and see the contents at the end.

Comment: Suggest you provide a fuller explanation of expected behavior and what needs to be done differently

Comment: So when you clicked `question 1` then 1st div should show and so on?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Swati. I tried but it just gets me the last question all the time, it should show corresponding questions when clicked on numbers at the end.

Comment: @AT-2017 check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/6mLfdgoq/5/) let me know if that works.

Comment: This looks promising and post it as a separate answer @Swati. I'll do a final testing and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to compare `if (id.match(id2)) {` because your questions are shown in sequence so we can use `divs.eq(id)..` to show only div which is clicked by user and to show answer we can pass this `id` value to `show_data1(indexes1)` to show answer as well when question is clicked.Also , i have subtract one from the id value because div index will start from `0`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hideSection2").hide();

  divs = $(".divs").children();
  divs.each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  var index = 0,
    divs = $(".divs").children();

  //declare
  var indexes = 0;
  $(".button").click(function() {
    //get div length
    var lengths = divs.length;
    //checking if btn clicked is next
    if ($(this).is('#next')) {
      //checking if value if less then length
      if ((indexes < (lengths - 1))) {
        //increment
        //remove 
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        console.log("in  - " + indexes)
        //show div
        index = (index + 1) % divs.length;
        divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
        //to show result
        show_data1(indexes);
        indexes++;
      } else {
        $(".hideSection2").show();
        $(".hideSection1").hide();
        console.log("i am in last question reached")
        $(this).prop('disabled', true); //disable
        $(this).css("background-color", "#00FFFF"); //chnagecolor

        $("#prev").css("background-color", "blue");

      }
    } else if ($(this).is('#prev')) {
      //chcking id value is not 0
      if (indexes != 0) {
        //remove 
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        indexes--;
        //show
        index = (index - 1) % divs.length;
        divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
        console.log("back  - " + indexes)
        show_data1(indexes); //show result
      } else {
        console.log("no back question")
        //disabled
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        //add color chnage
        $(this).css("background-color", "#00FFFF");
        $("#next").css("background-color", "blue");

      }
    }
  });

  function show_data1(indexes1) {
    //pass indexes value to get required div
    var $container = $('.divs').children().eq(indexes1);

    var id = $container.find(".h2Val").text().trim();
    var $checked = $container.find('.cbCheck:checked');
    var values = $checked.map(function() {
      return this.value
    }).get();
    //console.clear()
    console.log('ID: ' + id + ' has ' + $checked.length + ' checked');
    console.log('Values: ', values.join())

  }

  $(".getVal").click(function() {
//get id
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $(".hideSection1").show();
    $(".hideSection2").hide();
    //subtract one , because div starts from 0 ,1..etc
    var new_id= id - 1;
   //show div
    divs.eq(new_id).show().siblings().hide();
    index = new_id; //settting value of index again for click of next button
    indexes = new_id; //setting value for index
    show_data1(indexes) //show answer as well when user click of question no.

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideSection1">
  <div class="divs">
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="h2Val">1</div>
      <div>What's the capital of England?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val1" class="cbCheck" name="val1" value="London" />London</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val2" class="cbCheck" name="val2" value="New York" />New York</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="heading">
      <div class="h2Val">2</div>
      <div>Who invented computer?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val3" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val4" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val5" class="cbCheck" name="val5" value="Sir Isaac Newton" />Sir Isaac Newton</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="h2Val">3</div>
      <div>Who invented computehttr?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="button" id="prev">Previous</a>
  <a class="button" id="next">Next</a>
</div>

<div class="hideSection2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="divs2">
        <a class="getVal" data-id="1">1</a>
        <a class="getVal" data-id="2">2</a>
        <a class="getVal" data-id="3">3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm @Swati and made it work accordingly. Thank you a lot for your time and effort, I really appreciate it. Could you suggest one thing or share any similar example with `jQuery` to change icon state? Say if I click on an icon, it should change to another icon and when clicked again, will revert to its original state. See this - https://ibb.co/w4Nbz0Z and https://ibb.co/JqPd7dQ. Initially the first image is shown and when clicked, it should be similar to the second image.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368828/10606400) answer will help you to achieve that .