# Image toggle using replace

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images like that:

```
<div class="prizes">
    <img src="img/prize1-normal.png" width="102" height="137">
</div> 

<div class="prizes">
    <img src="img/prize2-normal.png" width="102" height="137">
</div>
```

And so on.

I need to replace image when it clicks. So I wrote this script:

```
$('.prizes').on('click', function(){
    file = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    if(file.indexOf('clicked') == -1){
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr("src").replace("-normal", "-clicked");
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", src);
    }

});
```

Works fine. But now a need to toggle the previous clicked image to normal. How can I do this?

Comment: "previous clicked", you mean image which has been clicked earlier?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062731/jquery-toggle-to-change-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add it to the else:

```
$('.prizes').on('click', function(){
    var file = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    var src = (file.indexOf('clicked') == -1) ? file.replace("-normal", "-clicked") : file.replace("-clicked", "-normal");

    $(this).find('img').attr("src", src);
});
```

**example:**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/KR2s8/

Comment: Pete, when I click in one item, the other, if was clicked, must to turn into normal.

Comment: @marcelo2605 ah ok that was never stated.  Try this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KR2s8/5/

Comment: Thanks Pete! Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
css

 .imag1{ background:url("../img/prize1-normal.png") no-repeat;width:102px; height:137px;}
 .imag2{ background:url("../img/prize2-normal.png") no-repeat;width:102px; height:137px;}


 var count=1;
 $(".prizes").live('click', function() {
    if(opacity==1){                       
$(".prizes").removeClass('imag2');
$(".prizes").addClass('imag1')
 count=2;
    }

    else{
count=1;    
$(".prizes").removeClass('imag1');
    $(".prizes").addClass('imag2');
    } 
});
```